# How To apply vectorization on for loop in Matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

Can anyone tell me how vectorize the following:

```
a = randi([6 10],5);; 
c = unique(a);
d = [1:5]; % some comparison Values length should be equal to length(c)

Mat = zeros(size(a));
for i = 1:length(c)
  Mat(a==c(i)) = d(i);
end
```

Result:

```
     3     1     5     3     3
     3     5     4     2     3
     5     1     3     3     3
     2     2     2     3     3
     3     5     5     3     4
```

Here 6 is replaced by 1, 7 is replaced  by 2, etc.

This is of course just an example; my real `Mat` is more like 2000×2000.

Comment: I started formulating an answer with the old version of your question; the new version seems a lot simpler actually :) Ah well, I think it's enough to get you going.

Comment: Well, it was indeed *so* simple, that I just planted another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** read my other answer first

To answer the question in your latest edit:

```
[~, inds] = histc(a(:), c);
Mat = reshape(d(inds), size(a));
```

Doing a similar test for 600×100 data:

```
a = randi(500,[600 100]); 
c = unique(a);
d = randi(20, size(c));

tic
Mat = zeros(size(a));
for ii = 1:length(c)
  Mat(a==c(ii)) = d(ii);
end
toc


tic
[~, inds] = histc(a(:), c);
Mat2 = reshape(d(inds), size(a));
toc

isequal(Mat,Mat2)
```

Gives the following:

```
Elapsed time is 0.166673 seconds.  %// your method
Elapsed time is 0.006669 seconds.  %// my method
ans =                              %// yes they're equal
    1
```

The speeds again differ by a factor of ~250.

Comment: +1 great! I didn't know about the second output of `histc`, it seems to be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: this is an answer to the original question; the second edit changed the question completely, so the answer below no longer applies. The edit greatly simplifies the problem, so this answer is still a good place to start.

Basically, all unique values of `a` will be replaced by corresponding values in `b`. That implies the matrix to analyze is `b`, and the only difficulty lies in the fact that the condition `b < d` must hold for *corresponding* indices in `b`.

To do this, you can simply bin all elements of `a` in groups defined by `c` and determine what group each element in `b` belongs to. That information can be used to find the proper indices in `d`.

In other words:

```
NewMat = b;
[~, inds] = histc(a(:), c);
NewMat(NewMat(:) > d(inds)) = 0;
```

A small test to compare the performance and validate the equality of the two methods:

```
a = randi(1000, 74,100);
b = randi(1000, 74,100);

c = unique(a);
d = randi(1000, size(c)); % some comparison Values

%// Your method
tic
NewMat = zeros(size(a));
for i = 1:length(c)
  Mat = zeros(size(a));
  Mat(a==c(i)) = b(a==c(i));
  Mat(Mat > d(i)) =0;
  NewMat = NewMat + Mat;
end
NewMat1 = NewMat;
toc

%// My method
tic
[~,inds] = histc(a(:), c);
b(b(:) > d(inds)) = 0;
NewMat2 = b;
toc

%// validate solution
isequal(NewMat1, NewMat2)
```

Results:

```
%// 74 × 100
Elapsed time is 0.151808 seconds.   %// your method 
Elapsed time is 0.001007 seconds.   %// my method
ans =                               %// yes, they're equal
     1
```

So a factor of ~150 performance increase. Using not 74×100 but 740×1000 gives

```
%// 740 × 1000
Elapsed time is 27.587543 seconds.  %// your method
Elapsed time is 0.111467 seconds.   %// my method
ans =                               %// yes, they're equal
     1
```

or a factor of ~250 difference. So apparently, your method also scaled worse than the `histc` approach.

Comment: @user2851655: also see my other answer, which answers your question as it currently is.

Comment: @user2851655: you're welcome; I enjoy these kinds of puzzles, so it was my pleasure really :)